# Generating a scatterplot from a greyscale intensity map

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, random

Using matplotlib(or if there exists anything else), i want to populate a scatterplot image by using a grey scale image as its distribution. I have found many resource to create heat maps from images but not the other way around.

The input image will be like [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M-4fxePSjdr37BAb0YJRX9w_zEzlQThw/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: What will the inputs and corresponding output images look like? Please share the code you have tried so far. Thank you.

Comment: The input image looks something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M-4fxePSjdr37BAb0YJRX9w_zEzlQThw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For such an input i would like to populate a scatter plot which has a linear distribution. As per code i am not sure of how to start with such a problem

Comment: There is no permission to view that link.

Comment: my bad, try it now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M-4fxePSjdr37BAb0YJRX9w_zEzlQThw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble understanding what you want to do. So far I've understood you want to start with a line and make something linear...

Comment: No let me explain it again. I have a set of input images like the one you saw before. i want from the input to generate a scatterplot where the whiter sections are more densely populated than the darker sections. so for an input like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j3hCqtFKO7_i8FIdQ6_8IjsJeS2GvAef/view?usp=sharing  will create a scatterplot with gaussian distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're going for, but I'm not certain. I also don't really understand what this would be used for so I'm extra uncertain about this answer, but here goes:

So by loading the image we can evaluate each pixel position and its intensity. We can use that intensity as a "fitness" value and probabilistically add it to our plot so that we can get some of that "density" of points that you want to see. I picked a really simple equation as a decider (I just cubed the value), but feel free to replace that with whatever you want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# select func
def selection(value):
    return value**3 >= random.randint(0, 255**3);

# populate the sample
def populate(img):
    # get res
    h, w = img.shape;

    # go through and populate
    sx = [];
    sy = [];
    for y in range(0, h):
        for x in range(0, w):
            val = img[y, x];

            # use intensity to decide if it gets in
            # replace with what you want this function to look like
            if selection(val):
                sx.append(x);
                sy.append(h - y); # opencv is top-left origin
    return sx, sy;


# I'm using opencv to pull the image into code, use whatever you like
# matplotlib can also do something similar, but I'm not familiar with its format
img = cv2.imread("circ.png");
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# lets take a sample
sx, sy = populate(img);

# find the bigger square size
h, w = img.shape;
side = None;
if h > w:
    side = h;
else:
    side = w;

# make a square graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots();
ax.scatter(sx, sy, s = 4);
ax.set_xlim((0, side));
ax.set_ylim((0, side));
x0,x1 = ax.get_xlim();
y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim();
ax.set_aspect(abs(x1-x0)/abs(y1-y0));
fig.savefig("out.png", dpi=600);
plt.show();
```

Feel free to replace opencv with whatever image library you're comfortable with. I'm pretty sure matplotlib can open images as well, but openCV is what I'm most familiar with so I used that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to generate random coordinates that follow a distribution described by a grayscale image: the brighter each point, the more likely that point's coordinates will be generated. Your problem can thus be solved by a [rejection sampler](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Rejection_Sampling), as follows.

Assume you know the width and height of the image in pixels, call them *w* and *h*.

1. Generate two random numbers: one in the interval [0, *w*), and [0, *h*). These are the *x* and *y* coordinates, respectively.
2. Get the pixel at the given coordinates *x* and *y* in the image. This can be done using interpolation, but describing interpolation techniques is beyond the scope of this answer. For this reason, we will use only the nearest pixel ("nearest neighbor") in the image: take the pixel at coordinate floor(*x*) and floor(*y*) (and step 1 devolves to generating random *integers*). Convert the pixel somehow to a number *p* in the interval [0, 1]; in this answer we will assume black is 0 and white is 1, to simplify matters.
3. With probability *p*, return the point (*x*, *y*). Otherwise, go to step 1.

Roughly speaking, the time complexity of this algorithm depends on the numbers of "bright points" the input image has, compared to the number of "dark points". In general, the "brighter" the image, the higher the acceptance rate (and the faster the algorithm runs).